# mysql query is taking forever to load

Tags: mysql

the below query is taking forever, can anyone make this faster
please note that I do to have much data that delays the process..

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select t1.time,t1.noise,t2.movement 
from noise t1 left join movement t2
on t1.time = t2.time
UNION
select t2.time,
t1.noise,t2.movement 
from noise t1 right join movement t2
on t1.time = t2.time
) tab
where time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like figuring out what part of the query is going slowly? You've provided NO details about your table structure, execution plan, etc... so there's essentialy nothing we can do to help.

Comment: Presumably there won't be any duplicates returned from the UNION - if so , try UNION ALL instead.

Answer (score 1):

Some helpful tips to help you identify the bottleneck and improve your query performance:

First, use the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) command on each query to [understand how MySQL will process the query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html). It will show you how many rows it must consider to run the query, how tables will be joined, and what indexes will be used. This is known as the *execution plan*.

For example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT t1.time, t1.noise, t2.movement 
FROM noise t1
LEFT JOIN movement t2 ON t1.time = t2.time;
```

That query will show you the execution plan for the first subquery.

As @mikeb suggests in his answer, you will want to create indexes on tables that do not have them to speed up queries. Think of an index as a "table of contents" for a particular column. ([How MySQL uses indexes.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html))

Finally, consider that your subqueries are evaluating the entire `movement` and `noise` tables. Both produce results that presumably consider or even contain all rows from those tables. Once both subqueries are combined (with `UNION`), the outer query eliminates rows based on the `time` column (keeping only the last 7 hours). You may want to move this conditional logic to the subqueries to produce only the rows you are interested in. Union those results, *then* order by time.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT t1.time, t1.noise, t2.movement 
    FROM noise t1
    LEFT JOIN movement t2
        ON t1.time = t2.time
    WHERE t1.time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
        AND t2.time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)

    UNION

    SELECT t2.time, t1.noise, t2.movement 
    FROM noise t1
    RIGHT JOIN movement t2
        ON t1.time = t2.time
    WHERE t1.time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
        AND t2.time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
) tab
ORDER BY time;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure without your table structure, but based on your query you need to add indexes on `noise.time` and `movement.time`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

```
CREATE INDEX ix_noise_time ON noise (time);
CREATE INDEX ix_movement_time ON movement (time);
```